# What is the entry point in a CXF generated web service?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, contract-first

Using a contract-first approach, I generated a web service from a WSDL, using CXF.

The web service loads fine by Tomcat 7 and responds properly to SOAP messages.

But while I understand the auto-generated Java classes from the WSDL and XSD, I am not sure I know where the entry point is (so that I can [enable validation](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html), for example).

Since the familiar main() method is only a default entry point and is [not mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897323/1864054), I am assuming that CXF uses a different entry point for that purpose.

When I build the web service (using a pom.xml that contains the CXF plugin), only 2 packages are generated (sufficient for establishing a *working* web service):

1. One for the WSDL itself, containing only 3 Java modules: ObjectFactory.java, MyBinding.java, MyService.java
2. The second is for the XSD schema, containing a Java class for each and every type defined in the schema.

I am suspecting that MyService.java, which extends a class named `Service` is where I should be looking for that entry point. But **how does it do "the magic"?**

BTW, I tried figuring this out from the Tomcat console, but that's all the web service logs upon startup:

```
Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 04 11:27:47 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@17392df: defining beans [org.springframework.context.
annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.anno
tation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanF
actoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindin
gFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory,org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer,myserviceWS,myserviceBinding]; root of factor
y hierarchy

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:47 AM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://myws.example.com/ns}MyService from WSDL: file:/C:/Users/Daniel/myws/src/main/wsdl/myws.wsdl

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:48 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /myservice/soap

Oct 4, 2013 11:27:48 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1107 ms
```

CXF seems to be hiding the implementation details very well, but I would like to know where to hook my initialization customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CXFServlet is generally the entry point for your service.  Tomcat routes the HTTP request to your webapp, and the servlet-mapping defines the Servlet that receives the request.  If you want to intercept the request before it reaches CXF, you could write a Servlet [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

For simple validation needs, CXF does support [schema validation via configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint?).

If you want to do fancier things to a message before it reaches your service, and benefit from the functionality of CXF, I would recommend becoming familiar with  CXF Interceptors.  They are very powerful, and can intercept a message at any number of phases before it reaches the service, and after it exits the service.  The CXF documentation has [details on the phases and instructions on writing an Interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html).

Comment: Thanks for an excellent and educating answer. As for the *schema validation via configuration*, since I can already see some validation being done by the web service, I am assuming it is turned on by default and thus the `<jaxws:endpoint` may not be needed. Am I right? However, the validation doesn't cover all rules specified in the schema and so I am suspecting a [cxf.xml](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html) is needed. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: OK, got it (in regard to *schema validation via configuration*): It turns out that the reference to `cxf.xml` was somewhat confusing because what they really referring to was the "application context" XML that must exist anyway and that could be named **anything**... Mine was named `beans.xml` and all I had to do to enable schema validation was to add `<jaxws:properties> <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" /> </jaxws:properties>` to the already defined `<jaxws:endpoint` element. All is well now.